# Android coundown in View class

Tags: java, android, view, countdown, ondraw

I am trying to make a circle appear after 3 seconds and disappear after more 3 seconds.

```
public class TestView extends View{

public TestView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);

    Paint circle = new Paint();
    circle.setColor(Color.BLUE);


    CountDownTimer count = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        public void onFinish() {

            CountDownTimer count = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 40, circle);

                }

                public void onFinish() {

                }

             }.start();

        }

     }.start();



}
```

Is this way a good way to make this task?
but he ask me to make canvas and paint as final. and how should I delete the circle?

Comment: add a boolean variable = shouldDrawCircle = true; , initialize it with true, and when you draw the circle , make it false, and then before drawing on removing , test on that variable to know if you should draw or remove the circle , if shouldDrawCircle == true // draw circle , else , remove it